# ArrayList syntax error

Tags: java, syntax, arraylist

I tried writing a small program, but it will not compile. Eclipse shows the following errors on the last line:

- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
   construct(s)
- Syntax error on token "200000", delete 
   this token

  ```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  public class Books{
    ArrayList<String> booksDB = new ArrayList<String>();
    booksDB.ensureCapacity(200000);        //Compilation Errors
  }
  ```

Comment: That line needs to go in a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Books{
  ArrayList<String> booksDB = new ArrayList<String>();
  booksDB.ensureCapacity(200000);        //Compilation Errors
}
```

You might be under the impression that this code is executing sequentially (from top to bottom) but that is not the case. What you are doing is creating a private instance field named `booksDB` that every instance of `Books` will carry.

Most likely, you want that code to go in the Books constructor (which gets called whenever a `new` instance of `Books` is created. Try the following:

```
public class Books {
    private ArrayList<String> booksDB;  // this is a field of the Books class

    // when we create a new Books instance, we will initialize the booksDB field
    public Books() {
        booksDB = new ArrayList<String>();
        booksDB.ensureCapacity(20000);
    }
}
```

Then use as follows:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Books b = new Books(); // the Books object is constructed, and its private field booksDB is initialized as we specified.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Except for declarations and imports, all code in Java must reside inside a method (or, as discussed below, inside initializers, which are essentially methods too):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Books {
    ArrayList<String> booksDB = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void doSomething() {
        booksDB.ensureCapacity(200000);        //Compilation Errors
    }
}
```

Since you seem to be initializing the contents of the object, you might want to put that line in a *constructor*, which is a method that is automatically run on newly-created objects:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Books {
    ArrayList<String> booksDB = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Books() {
        booksDB.ensureCapacity(200000);        //Compilation Errors
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `static {...}`?

Comment: @arshajii: A static constructor is also a method.

Comment: I'm referring to static initialization blocks.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "static constructor", I think you mean static initializer (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7)

Comment: ..or an instance initialization block

Comment: @arshajii and @TofuBeer: My bad; I used the C# term for C#'s similar concept. However, a static initialization block will be compiled to a method called `clinit`. The instance initalization blocks are compiled into the constructor. So they're all, in that sense, methods - however, I'll grant that they're usually considered to be separate constructs.

Comment: But I don't think it should be considered a 'method' in the normal sense. You cannot, for instance, 'call' a static initialization block like you can a method.

Comment: @arshajii: Fair enough; I've noted this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use constructor of ArrayList that accepts initial capacity like below

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Books{
   ArrayList<String> booksDB = new ArrayList<String>(200000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access variables ( booksDB ) only from methods. That's all you have to do.